# DIV and CSS: Floating box inside semi transparent div

Tags: html, css, visualforce

I am creating this in a visualforce page but due to stackexchange policy I need to post web development questions here.

I have the following HTML code:

```html
<div style="position: absolute;  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;  opacity: 0.75; z-index: 1000; background-color: gray;">
  &nbsp;
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; z-index: 1001; margin: 10% 25%; color:white; font-weight:bold; text-align: center;">
  <h>Transferring Records...</h><br />
  <img src="/img/loading32.gif"/><br />
  <h>This may take a minute or two...</h><br />
</div >
```

Which generates a full screen gray overlay and then my text and image in the center.

What I am trying to do is create a smaller white box around my text as well so it is easier to read. Can anyone help me with that?

Here is a screenshot of current setup:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is very tightly coupled code design/structure wise and the use of `&nbsp;` and `<h>` tags seems so legitimately nineties.

Comment: I am not a web developer and only use it in very basic ways for visualforce pages.

Comment: @MattM can you use style sheets? Or are you stuck with inline styles?

Comment: Yes, I can but I only have like your CSS and a few other lines in my entire page as VF has some built in styles with the different components. So I don't see much point in creating a separate static resource that is harder in some ways to tweak on the go.

Comment: FYI, Here is how they can be setup in VF
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_stylesheet.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would change your structure a slight bit and decouple your CSS - if only for your own sanity when reading the thing in between content (if you want to you can simple include it in a `<style type="text/css"></style>` tag and it would work as well.

Since you want your white box to be inside your container, why not structure it like that? By fixing the outer container (with class `overlay`, referenced as `.overlay` in CSS) you can now position the inner box correctly, by moving it 50% from the left and top and then transform the box itself using `translate`, moving it by minus half its width and height. Now your structure makes sense and you can do whatever you want with your inner box:

```css
div.overlay {
  position: fixed;  
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000; 
  background-color: gray;
  background-color: rgba(150,150,150,.5);
}
div.overlay div {
  position: absolute; 
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  color: black; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5)
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <div>
    <h>Transferring Records...</h>
    <br /><img src="/img/loading32.gif"/>
    <br /><h>This may take a minute or two...</h>
  </div>
</div>
```

This structure also makes it easy to work with as everything is simply contained in one single element, and you control everything in it. Easier to debug, easier to reason about (the relationship of the elements is obvious) and your CSS can target specifically `div`s that are nested inside boxes with the class `overlay`.

Comment: That is just what i needed. Thank you! I made one small tweak however and change the alpha value to 1.0 on the white box to accomplish my goal.

Comment: Yeah you can edit all those colors any way you want, its the principle that matters! Also - in case you think this might be used on older browsers - be sure that you define a regular hex color (say `#fff` for white) _before_ using `rgba` to make sure older browsers still get _a_ color.

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for something like this?

```html
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; opacity: 0.75; z-index: 1000; background-color: gray;"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; z-index: 1001; margin: 10% 25%; color:white; font-weight:bold; text-align: center;">
 <div style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);padding: 20px;">
  <h>Transferring Records...</h><br>
  <img src="/img/loading32.gif"><br>
  <h>This may take a minute or two...</h>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a white background to your `div`, use `background: white;`. The problem you then have is your text is also white, so you have to change the `color` to `color: black` (or some other color).

Knowing SalesForce, your probably would want rounded corners, so add `border-radius: 10px;` for that :)

To round the corners more, increase the `10px` to a higher number, say `20px`, and to round them less, decrease the number to say `5px`

As snippet below

```html
<div style="position: absolute;  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;  opacity: 0.75; z-index: 1000; background-color: gray;">
  &nbsp;
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; z-index: 1001; margin: 10% 25%; color:black; font-weight:bold; text-align: center; background: white; border-radius: 10px;">
  <h>Transferring Records...</h>
  <br />
  <img src="/img/loading32.gif" />
  <br />
  <h>This may take a minute or two...</h>
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: CalvT, I had tried that in the past however SF kept ignoring my code and would either not generate the white div or just not generate the entire apex:actionstatus code.

Comment: "To add a white background to your div, use background: white;. The problem you then have is your text is also white, so you have to change the color to color: black (or some other color)"

Comment: @MattM The only difference between that part and the answer you accepted is instead of white he put an alpha value, which makes no difference to the functionality.